# Limit user access to specific fields in front end Microsoft Access database

Tags: ms-access, frontend

I have an Access database that contains worker information.

Some of this information is required by my coworkers to do their jobs, but some fields contain confidential information that they shouldn't have access to.

What I would like to do is split the database, with the back end encrypted and the front end compiled, so they can't change anything.

I don't have a problem with this aspect. The problem is that the front end that they would have access to would contain the entire table.

I want to know if there is a way to limit which fields are displayed in the front end database so my password protected back end would still contain everything, but front end users would only have access to the data I want them to. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Don't allow users to work directly with tables and queries, only forms and reports (hide the navigation pane and disable shortcut menu and hide/customize the ribbon). Need some way for Access to 'know' who user is. Have a Users table and then either a login procedure or grab Windows USERNAME, then lookup user in table. Open form based on user permissions, hiding buttons or data controls accordingly. This is a common topic.

Comment: Ultimately MS Access is not a secure environment. You can "kind of" lock things and you can hide things but all it takes is a user knowing to open the database while holding down the Shift key and everything is exposed. For real security you need to move your data on a secure back end like SQL Server and just use Access for the front end.

Comment: I decided to ditch the idea of a split DB as a solution to my problem. Instead, I made a regular DB, which I then encrypted. I then made a make table query that included only the fields I wanted users to have access to and set up a form with some code that would rerun the query and overwrite the table every time I close the DB, so the table with my selected fields is always up to date. Then I made a separate DB and made a linked table to my query table. This way they can access those fields in the unencrypted DB, but if they tried to access the full table they would be prompted for a password